# call one class in another class's while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get solve (a bubble sort algorithm variant) working as it should. It should take an instance of the MarblesBoard class and, then either switch the first two items (if neither = 0) or rotate them, print the board and repeat until solved (marbles are sorted in ascending order).

Here is the MarblesBoard class:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = list(marbles) 
        print(marbles)
    def switch(self):
        self.input[1], self.input[0] = self.input[0], self.input[1]
        print self.input     
    def rotate(self):
        return self.input[1:] + self.input[:1]
        print self.input
    def is_solved(self):
        if all(self.input[i] <= self.input[i+1] for i in range(len(self.input)-1)):
            return True
            print "True"
        else:
            print "Not solved!"

board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
board.switch()
board.rotate()
board.is_solved()
```

Output:

```
(3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 0, 8, 2, 5)
[6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 0, 8, 2, 5]
Not solved!
```

Here is the Solver class:

```
class Solver:
    def __init__(self, MarblesBoard):
        #print self
        self.board = MarblesBoard
    def solve(self):
        if all(self.board.input[i] <= self.board.input[i+1] for i in range(len(self.board.input)-1)):
            return True
            #break
        else:
            if self.board.input[0] & self.board.input[1] != 0:
                if self.board.input[1] < self.board.input[0]:
                    self.board = self.board.switch()
                    print self.board
                else:
                    self.board = self.board.rotate()
                    print self.board
            else:
                self.board = self.board.rotate()
                print self.board
        return


player = Solver(board)
player.solve()
```

Output:

```
[6, 7, 4, 1, 0, 8, 2, 5, 3]
```

I don't think return works as I would like it to in my Sorter class, and I've tried replacing the initial if else with a while loop by placing all the inner if else loops inside of it while the condition is false. This caused an infinite loop. Please advise.

Comment: Your error description is too vague, at least for me.

Comment: too vague for me too. Btw, you shouldn't name a variable the same as class's name, it's dangerous.

Comment: I want the first inner if loop to keep working until the main outer if loop returns True

Comment: Your rotate method is wrong for your use. You are just returning values without storing them. You are talking about loops, there aren't any.  You only have if conditions.

Comment: I edited my code (see original post) to change the board after each action in the solve method. I also deleted all but one return statement, which I was hoping could loop the main if else statement. This doesn't seem to be the case. I want to avoid an infinite loop. Advice?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output, @FredericBastiat?